# populate the specific column based on the condition

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Is there a way on how to populate the specific column based on the condition? I want to populate the column name [Last] if the column index is equal to 1 and the equivalent name is equal to [First].

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

  columns : ColumnModel[];

  constructor() { 
     this.columns = [
        {id:1,name:"Seq No."},
        {id:2,name:"First"},
        {id:3,name:"Last"},
        {id:4,name:"Handle"}
     ];
  }
}

interface ColumnModel{
    id?: number;
    name?: string;
  }
```

```html
<table class="table">
    <tr *ngFor="let col of columns;index as i">
        <th scope="col">Seq No.</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col" *ngIf="i == 1 && col.name == First">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
     </tr>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Based from my code above, this tag `<tr *ngFor="let col of columns;index as i">`  repeats 4 times, which shouldn't be since it is a header. And, I put this code `*ngIf="i == 1 && col.name == First"` so that the [Last] column name should be visible if the index 1 is equal to [First].

Is there a way to get my expected output? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear! Why are you running `*ngFor` on table header, when usually a table has only one header section? You code is creating 4 header sections since `this.columns` has four elements. Also, in what scenario "if the column index is equal to 1 and the equivalent name is equal to [First]" will ever be true?

Answer (score 0):

Your `*ngFor` is in `<tr>` which causing the `tr` to render four times, cause you have four elements in `this.columns`. Have you tried having one set of  like this:

```
<tr>
   <th scope="col">Seq No.</th>
   <th scope="col">First</th>
   <th scope="col" *ngIf="columns[1].name == 'First'">Last</th>
   <th scope="col">Handle</th>
</tr>
```